Is it possible to continue baking a cache from the last .blob file, after a crash?
I've got a simulation nodes particle setup which is around 2000 frames long. Blender won't bake it at the particle density I need - it keeps crashing after a few hundred frames, and the only way I can get it to cache end-to-end is by dropping the particle density a lot more than I want (I need it around 5000, and the most I've managed to cache all the way is 1250).
Trying to bake it with a pre-existing cache via the Physics tab doesn't do anything - the playhead skips through the frame range really quickly, as the node setup is deactivated. Using the Bake node seems to just delete the cache and start from the beginning again. Is there any way to force Blender to pick up from where it left off? I'm only guessing, but wouldn't the .blob files contain velocity and other custom attribute information per particle, rather than just position data?
Using Blender 4.1.0, 128GB RAM, 24C Threadripper 3960X.
